# Is it possible to have a "touchesBegan" on a UITableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

`-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   touchStartTime = [event timestamp];
}`

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { 
    NSTimeInterval touchTimeDuration = [event timestamp] - touchStartTime; 
}
```

touchStartTime is defined at class level.

Any idea why this won't recognise the touch events?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Personally, from my experience with the UITableView, I don't think that you can use the touch events.

You may have to look into other ways of dealing with this.  For example, try using the selection as a helper?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible to do.  I setup a test project with a custom UITableViewCell subclass and defined the methods in the same way that you have, adding a log to the touchesEnded to print the touchTimeDuration.  I ran it in the simulator and it seems to work for me.

How are you determining if your code is recognizing the events?

Comment: Hey Mike, cheers for the reply.

The code works fine, at the bottom layer of the XIB file (i.e. the UIImageView).

I can touch and hold, when I lift my finger off of the UIImageView the NSLog states the time I held my finger on the screen. But won't initialise on the UITableViewCell (which is a custom cell, if that makes any difference).